# Allow only specific tag in <h:outputText>

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `<h:outputText>` which displays some description (Alphanumeric + emoticons).

Here is my issue. I want to allow only specific tag (in my case `<img>` tag for emoticons) to be allowed in the outputText.
I currently have,
`<h:outputText id='someid' escape='false'/>` which allows all the html tags. Is there anyway I can allow my `<img>` and escape all other tags?

I'm open to using jquery as well but not sure how to go ahead with it.

Note: I'm using Primefaces and the outputText value is pre-fetched from EO and displayed on page load.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for the alternate link. But is it that complex to have a jquery/js function just for allowing the <img> tag instead of using a parser?

Comment: In JS/jQuery it's too late. HTML has at that point already been produced by server and consumed by client.